# Typescripts Compile-On-Save generates incorrect modules

Tags: typescript, amd

I've just updated Web Essentials 2012 and found that now I need to use the built-in compile functionality of the `Typescript` plugin.

So first I added in the extra code to the project. http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>true</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>false</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

However when I compile, I find a few things:

- My `.min.js` files no longer are being compiled.
- I have no preview window (sad times).
- And my `.js` file is incorrectly generated.

This `.js`:

```
/// <reference path="../_references.d.ts" />
var ko = require('knockout-mapping');
var library = require("./foo/library");

var myModule;
(function (myModule) {
    var Foo = (function () {
        function Foo(parameters) {
            this.parameters = parameters;
```

from this `.ts`:

```
import ko = require('knockout-mapping');
import library = require('foo/library');

module myModule {

   export class Foo {

      constructor(public parameters) {
```

The `import` statement is relative (wrong for my setup), and it is now using a `require` instead of `define`. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use compiler options to pass in amd : `CompilerOptions="-module amd"`

Spec : https://msbuildtypescript.codeplex.com/

Comment: How do I use this dll? Do I just dump it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TypeScript`?